# Prevent/Disable suspend in Ubuntu 17.10

Tags: 17.10

How can I prevent and totally disable suspend in Ubuntu 17.10 ? My HP Elitebook totally freezes after suspend, so I want to remove it as a possibility.

Output from find:

```
sindre@saspire:~$ find /lib/systemd /etc/systemd -name "*sleep*.service"
/lib/systemd/system/systemd-hybrid-sleep.service
sindre@saspire:~$ find /lib/systemd /etc/systemd -name "*hiber*.service"
/lib/systemd/system/systemd-hibernate.service
/lib/systemd/system/systemd-hibernate-resume@.service
```

Answer (score 2):

You can disable it via systemd:

```
$ sudo systemctl disable hybrid-sleep
```

If you change your mind in the future you can enable it again:

```
$ sudo systemctl enable hybrid-sleep
```

More info:

```
man systemd-hybrid-sleep.service
```

Comment: cris@celite:~$ sudo systemctl disable hybrid-sleep
[sudo] password for cris: 
Failed to disable unit: Unit file hybrid-sleep.service does not exist.

Comment: Maybe they've changed the name in 17.10. Try to find it: find /lib/systemd /etc/systemd -name "\*sleep\*.service" or find /lib/systemd /etc/systemd -name "\*hiber\*.service"

Comment: I updated my question with output from find. How can I run it against the new name?

Comment: Yes, the name is changed. Use this command: $ sudo systemctl disable systemd-hybrid-sleep